# Why am I getting this unexpected string error?

Tags: javascript, string, syntax-error

I'm learning css + js + html rn and while making a simple pop-up message script, i started getting an unexpected string error in the following script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var xbg = prompt("Please enter your name!", "Henry Phillips");
  if (person === null || person == "")
  {
    txt= "Enter your name in the field.";
  } else {
    txt "Hello" + xbg + "! How are you today?"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

As console says, the string error is specifically located here:
[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzFsd.png)

Comment: You are missing an `=` symbol here: `txt = "Hello" + xbg + "! How are you today?" `

Comment: Looks like you forgot an equals symbol in the else part

Comment: You're missing the `=` sign.

Comment: Unexpectedly, indeed...

Comment: The error disappeared, but for some reason pop-up message isn't showing up :L

Comment: You forgot to define person too, rename xbg to person

Comment: In the if statement from where `person` variable come from? ask yourself. Also, in the else block you forgot `=` sign for `txt` variable re-assignment.

Comment: You also have to call function after it is defined: `function myFunction() { // your code }; myFunction()` <--

Comment: `var person =  prompt("Please enter your name!", "Henry Phillips"); document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person? "Hello" + person + "! How are you today?" :  "Enter your name in the field."`

Comment: @mplungjan Can you explain how *Enter you name in the field.*  if you don't reopen prompt ?

Comment: I would not want this to run more than once.

Answer (score 2):

There is some errors in your script.

First you forget the `=` in the else statment.

```
txt = "Hello " + xbg + "! How are you today?"
----^
```

The if condition don't test the good variable name, you can replace person by xbg.

```
if (xbg === null || xbg == "")
// or shorter
if (xbg && xbg.trim())
```

And finally, you don't call your script another time if user don't enter this name. You can use `setTimeout` to give some time to the user for read the message before open prompt another time.

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 500);
```

See complete fixed code below

```js
function myFunction() {
  var xbg = prompt("Please enter your name!", "");
  if (xbg === null || xbg == "")
  {
    txt = "Enter your name in the field.";
    setTimeout(myFunction, 500);
  } else {
    txt= "Hello " + xbg + "! How are you today?"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: But there are 3 errors in this op, is not just typo answer. Thanks for this information !

Comment: There are no errors in the script that is not easily figured out with a minimum of effort, like hitting F12 and look in the console. So this question is really not worth keeping for the future visitors.  Your's is one of the few answers that also adresses the logical error - also that logical error is a very simple beginner's fault that could have been explained in the comments so OP could delete the question

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name!", "Put Your Name");
  if (person.trim()) {
    txt = "Hello, " + person + "! How are you today?"
  } else {
    txt = "Enter your name in the field.";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

You can find the edited script here.

Comment: Earlier it was different , I edited ,but the the earlier one was also working.

Answer (score -1):

so basically you have a typo here: change **person** with **xbg**

```
function myFunction() {
  var xbg = prompt("Please enter your name!", "Henry Phillips");
  if (xbg === null || xbg == "")
  {
    txt= "Enter your name in the field.";
  } else {
    txt ="Hello" + xbg + "! How are you today?"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```